# Converting coordinates (latitude,longitude) to X,Y using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, polygon, coordinates, latitude-longitude

How can I convert the latitude and the longitude coordinates of a rectangle in Cartesian coordinates, so that I can store them in a geometry field using PostGIS?

Answer (score 3):

Check [ST_Transform](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Transform.html) from the very helpful [PostGIS docs](http://postgis.org/docs/index.html):

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((-71.1776585052917 42.3902909739571,-71.1776820268866 42.3903701743239, -71.1776063012595 42.3903825660754,-71.1775826583081 42.3903033653531,-71.1776585052917 42.3902909739571))',4326),2249)) As wgs_geom;
```